# How to use Parallel Strategies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have a function `frequencyBy` which I would like to parallelize. Here follows a simple test case:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.DeepSeq
import System.Environment

frequencyBy :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,Int)]
frequencyBy f as bs = map 
    (\a ->(a, foldr (\b -> if f a b then (+) 1 else id) 0 bs)) as

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x:xs <- getArgs
  let result = frequencyBy (==) [1::Int .. 10000] [1 .. (read x)] `using` 
                 parList rdeepseq
  print $ product $ map snd $ result
```

I would like to run the `map` in `frequencyBy` in parallel. I'm trying to achieve this using `parList rdeepseq` (all the other stuff in `main` is just to ensure not everything is optimized away). However, this doesn't work, two threads do twice as much work as one thread does in the same time. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If two threads do twice as much work as one thread in the same time, doesn't that mean it's parallelising properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be that the overhead is slowing things down, depending on how big *x* is; if the work you're doing in each spark is comparable to the time it takes to spawn each spark (and of course there's scheduling overhead, etc.), then you'll run into problems.

You could try [`parListChunk`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/latest/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v:parListChunk), e.g. `parListChunk 64 rdeepseq`; you'll have to experiment to figure out which chunk size to use. While your current strategy is creating a spark for every element of the list, `parListChunk` creates a spark for each chunk of a certain size in the list, and uses the strategy you specify sequentially over each element of that chunk.

By the way, the `foldr` in `frequencyBy` is probably slowing things down due to excessive thunk creation; something like

```
frequencyBy :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,Int)]
frequencyBy f as bs = map (\a -> (a, sum . map (const 1) . filter (f a) $ bs)) as
```

should fix that.

Of course, as always, make sure you're compiling with `-O2` and running with `+RTS -N`.

Comment: This isn't the same code; the OP's function is equivalent to `sum . map (const 1) $ filter (f a) bs` or `length $ filter (f a) bs`, although neither is an improvement for me (and using `length` is much slower).

Comment: `parListChunk 2 rdeepseq` already does the trick and makes sure it only takes half the time on two threads (as compared to one thread). This does seem strange though, why would evaluating chunks of 1 give to much overhead, while chunks of 2 lead to perfect parallelisation?

Comment: I used `sum . map (const 1) $ filter (f a) bs` before, but I found out that manually fusing it into a `foldr` was way faster.

Comment: @user352382: what value are you using for `x`?

Comment: @JohnL: Fixed, thanks! @user352382: Well, if a spark takes a given amount of time to spawn, then the work you're doing in that spark has to be sufficiently expensive, or the time it takes to spawn will result in too much overhead. If `parListChunk 2` works fine, then 2 just happens to be enough here :)

Comment: @user352382: By the way, with GHC, I think that `sum` on `[Int]` will use a `foldl'`, not a `foldr`, which is why I suggested it.

Answer (score 7):

I think your parallelism is too fine-grained.  `parList` attempts to evaluate every element in parallel, and there really isn't that much work for any one element.

When I change from `parList` to `parListChunk 500` the execution time increases by almost 50%; as I'm on a dual-core machine that's about as good as it gets.

For reference, I was testing with `x=20000`.